# Php not working on add more row (Form repeater)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am using form repeater to create an invoice. Invoices have multiple products which come from the database with the price. 
When I choose a product its price automatic appears to fee box and there are other input boxes like discount and percentage, which have values 0 0 by default. The first row works very fine. but when I click on add more button to generate next row to add another product.

In next row, I can choose the product from a drop-down. but its fee did not appear and other input box values like discount and percentage also disappear (They did not show up any default value.)

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="single" class="control-label">Select Invoice Type</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">Fee</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">Quantity</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">Discount</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">Total</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">Doctor %</div>
</div>
<div class="mt-repeater">
    <div data-repeater-list="group-b">
        <div data-repeater-item class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="invoice" class="form-control" name="invoice">
                        <option></option>
                        <?php
                            $select = mysqli_query(connection(), "select * from treatement");
                            while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
                                echo "<option value='$r[0]'>$r[name]</option>";
                            }
                         ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control"  placeholder="Fee" name="fees" id="fees">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" value="1" name="quantity" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Discount" name="discount">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" readonly name="total">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" placeholder="%" name="percentage">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-delete class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-create class="btn btn-info mt-repeater-add">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add More
    </a>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

And I use js function to compare fee of each product. This helps me display fee in a box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#invoice").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.get("get_fees.php", {
            id: value
        }, function(data) {
            $("#fees").val(data);
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Do you use `id="invoice"` in every row? IDs have to be unique, you should use a class instead of ID. And then see [Event binding on dynamically-created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) for the proper way to bind the event handler for them.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please.. dont use id like that. id must be unique, you should use class instead ID (see barmar comment)

```
<p id="test"></p>
<p id="test"></p>
<p id="test"></p>
```

should be

```
<p id="test1" class="test"></p>
<p id="test2" class="test"></p>
<p id="test3" class="test"></p>
```

do you that, i dont use same id, because id must be unique.

- 1 id must used by 1 element.
- 1 class can be used by many element

but, you can still hack this with. `$('select[id="invoice"]')`

and seems you create new dom , you can change this line

`$("#invoice").change(function() {`

become

`$("body").on('change', 'select[id="invoice"]', function() {`

> UPDATE: 
>   why you always change your first selector / the first id=fees. because you are using `$('#fees').val()`

you must specify that, with: get the parent (i make it with `closest()`), then find the specific id="fees" which you want to change

because you dont have anyspecific class that identify your parent repeater, i choose to add rowsdata class

change `<div data-repeater-item class="row">` with `<div data-repeater-item class="row rowsdata">`

and your script will looks like this

```
$("body").on('change', 'select[id="invoice"]', function() {
    var select = $(this);
    $.get("get_fees.php", {
        id: select.val()
    }, function(data) {
        select.closest('.rowsdata').find('input[id="fees"]').val(data); //if you still give id="fees" and dont have any class use this
        //select.closest('.rowsdata').find('.fees').val(data); if you already give class="fees", use this
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works when I replace script line and change the id="fees" to class. But When I change the product in 2nd or 3rd row it change the fee of above rows as well to same as the last one. Can you please help me with this

Comment: nice to hear that.